# Netbeans remove from navigator members

Tags: java, netbeans

I noticed that in the Netbeans navigator "action(Event evt, Object what)" is deprecated. Fair enough. I didn't use it directly in my code, but it came from the GUI automatic building, the *.form file.

My question is can I eliminate from the navigator all members which are not in the current file under investigation? In other words, I want to debug my file, not some file from inside the Windows module or somewhere else.

Comment: You can write or 'overwrite' templates for automatic building. (I'm sorry, if I  understood your question incorrectly)

Comment: I don't want to overwrite the templates, just remove from the Navigator any members which come from it. More generally, I just want the members which are in the current module, i.e. not "external" members.

Comment: I might be wrong, but it seems impossible for now...

Comment: It turns out to be trivial. In the Members box at the bottom right, the first icon is "Show inherited members". All I needed to do was uncheck that option.

Comment: Ha ha... Wow - something so obvious. I missed it (in my IDEs this option is unchecked by default).